# Selecting all elements within two xml tags

Tags: c#, openxml, word-automation

Does anyone know of a way to extract the xml contents of a bookmark in word using c#. I am trying to do some string replacement at a bookmark using openxml and am unable to select all the elements betwen a bookmark start and bookmark end tag.

Thanks

Comment: Once the XML tree is read into memory, won't all the elements between the start and end tag be descendants of the bookmark node?

Comment: well the bookmark node is a decendant of the pargraph node from what i understand(btw do you have any idea how i can read the tree into memory?)

Comment: I'm no OpenXML expert, but my point is that once you have an XML tree in memory you should be able to get the children of any node.  Once you have the children of the bookmark node, you can get the children's children, and the children's children's children, and so on until you have all the descendants of the bookmark node.  Those descendants will be exactly the elements between the bookmark start and end tag.

Comment: I think your real question is how to read the tree into memory.  Which library are you using for XML?

Comment: are there any good sources on how to read the xml structure? right now i am creating a wordprocessingdocument using the openxml sdk and not really an xml tree

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is not reading the XML Tree into memory but actually getting the nodes between two xml nodes. The start and end node of the xml document in ooxml are solo meaning there are no child nodes. These simply state there is the beginning of a bookmark and an end of a bookmark. It would make more sense to me if everything encapsulated in the bookmark would be a child node of a bookmark node rather than the current use of the xml tags.

Since xPath navigation doesnt really work well with this concept one thing you could do is loop through each node in the xDoc and look for the bookmarkstart and end tags. Adding everything betewwn the two to an array or a new xDoc. From that point you can further parse the nodes to get the data you need. Hope that makes sense.